# Нет отступов между колонками bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap, background, отступы

Верстка с сеткой bootstrap. Каждый div занимает по 4 колонки. Но почему то между блоками нет расстояния. Если смотреть в инспекторе, то они как бы есть, но background не оставляет места между блоками. Как исправить ситуацию? Фрагмент макета прикладываю. Бэкграунд сделал зеленым для наглядности.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: 100;

}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: 300;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: 500;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: 700;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: 900;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl', sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
}
                  /* Меню */
#header {
 background: url(../img/header.png) no-repeat center top;
 height: 747px;
}
.nav ul {
 margin-top: 32px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
.nav {
 padding-right: 0px;
}
.nav__main_menu_list {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: 900;
 margin-right: 20px;
 letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}
.nav__main_menu_list a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
}
.nav__main_menu_list a:hover {
 background: #386075;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 13px 12px;
 color: #fff;
}
.nav__main_menu_phone img {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding-right: 15px;
}
.nav__main_menu_phone {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.nav__main_menu_list:nth-child(5) {
 padding-right: 0;
}
      /* Конец Меню */

.heading h1 {
 font-size: 90px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 27px;
 margin-top: 200px;
}
.heading span {
 font-size: 51px;
 letter-spacing: 8px;
}
.heading__img {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 110px;
}
.advantages h2 {
 font-size: 42px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 77px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.advantages__list {
 background: green;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
.advantages h3 {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.advantages__list img:nth-child(1) {
 margin-top: 45px;
}
.advantages__list p {
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Болгария ждет Вас!</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header id="header">
  <nav>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2 logo">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-7 nav">
      <ul class="nav__main_menu">
       <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
        <a href="#">Главная</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
        <a href="#">О компании</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
        <a href="#">ВНЖ и ПМЖ в Болгарии</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
        <a href="#">Недвижимость и переезд</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 nav__main_menu_phone">
      <img src="img/phone_icon.png" alt="icon">
      +7 (495) 12-321-345<br>
      +7 (495) 12-321-345
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 heading">
     <h1>Болгария<br>
      <span>ждет Вас</span></h1>
      <div class="heading__img">
       <a href="#"><img src="img/heading.png" alt="d"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <section>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 advantages">
     <h2>Наши преимущества</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row advantages">
    <div class="col-md-4 advantages__list">
     <img src="img/advantages_left.png" alt="">
     <h3>Надежность</h3>
     <img src="img/advantages_line.png" alt="">
     <p>
      Мы всегда придем к вам на помощь в решении самых неоднозначных вопросов
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 advantages__list">
     <img src="img/advantages_top.png" alt="">
     <h3>Достоверность</h3>
     <img src="img/advantages_line.png" alt="">
     <p>
      Достоверность - главный принцип нашей работы. Мы знаем все тонкости переезда в Болгарию и оформления соответствующих документов
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 advantages__list">
     <img src="img/advantages_right.png" alt="">
     <h3>Компетентность</h3>
     <img src="img/advantages_line.png" alt="">
     <p>
      Наши специалисты с большим опытом работы помогут разобраться во всех юридических тонкостях переезда
      на ПМЖ в Болгарию
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: потому что это padding, отступы внутри. А не margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что это у колонки padding(внутренний отступ, а не внешний). Лучше всего не не навешивать на блоки формирующие сетку, классы смысловых блоков. Поместите свой смысловой блок вовнутрь колонки:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot');
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
  /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: 100;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot');
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
  /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: 300;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot');
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
  /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: 500;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.eot');
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
  /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: 700;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot');
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
  /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: 900;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.eot');
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
  /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Меню */

#header {
  background: url(../img/header.png) no-repeat center top;
  height: 747px;
}

.nav ul {
  margin-top: 32px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.nav {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.nav__main_menu_list {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-right: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}

.nav__main_menu_list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__main_menu_list a:hover {
  background: #386075;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 13px 12px;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__main_menu_phone img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.nav__main_menu_phone {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.nav__main_menu_list:nth-child(5) {
  padding-right: 0;
}


/* Конец Меню */

.heading h1 {
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 27px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.heading span {
  font-size: 51px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
}

.heading__img {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 110px;
}

.advantages h2 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 77px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.advantages__list {
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.advantages h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.advantages__list img:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.advantages__list p {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Болгария ждет Вас!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <nav>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2 logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 nav">
            <ul class="nav__main_menu">
              <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
                <a href="#">Главная</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
                <a href="#">О компании</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
                <a href="#">ВНЖ и ПМЖ в Болгарии</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
                <a href="#">Недвижимость и переезд</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__main_menu_list">
                <a href="#">Контакты</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav__main_menu_phone">
            <img src="img/phone_icon.png" alt="icon"> +7 (495) 12-321-345<br> +7 (495) 12-321-345
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 heading">
          <h1>Болгария<br>
            <span>ждет Вас</span></h1>
          <div class="heading__img">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/heading.png" alt="d"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 advantages">
          <h2>Наши преимущества</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row advantages">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="advantages__list">
            <img src="img/advantages_left.png" alt="">
            <h3>Надежность</h3>
            <img src="img/advantages_line.png" alt="">
            <p>
              Мы всегда придем к вам на помощь в решении самых неоднозначных вопросов
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="advantages__list">
            <img src="img/advantages_top.png" alt="">
            <h3>Достоверность</h3>
            <img src="img/advantages_line.png" alt="">
            <p>
              Достоверность - главный принцип нашей работы. Мы знаем все тонкости переезда в Болгарию и оформления соответствующих документов
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="advantages__list">
            <img src="img/advantages_right.png" alt="">
            <h3>Компетентность</h3>
            <img src="img/advantages_line.png" alt="">
            <p>
              Наши специалисты с большим опытом работы помогут разобраться во всех юридических тонкостях переезда на ПМЖ в Болгарию
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, все получилось. Еще вопрос, можно как то тексты и заголовки выровнять по горизонтали, не задавая каждому отдельный класс и не подгоняя марджинами?

Comment: Добавьте 1 раз padding для .advantages__list и никаких марджинов не надо будет.